# Laravel - Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to run a Laravel query that selects a particular field that appears more than once, and I got the error below.

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'no_of_service' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `cloudsubscriptions` inner join `service_package` on `cloudsubscriptions`.`package_id` = `service_package`.`id` group by `cloudsubscriptions`.`msisdn`, `service_package`.`title` having `no_of_service` > 1)

```php
$subscribers = Cloudsubscriptions::join("service_package", 
    "cloudsubscriptions.package_id", "=", "service_package.id")
    ->select("cloudsubscriptions.msisdn", "cloudsubscriptions.service_name", 
        "service_package.title",
        DB::raw("COUNT(cloudsubscriptions.msisdn) as 'no_of_service'"))
    ->groupBy("cloudsubscriptions.msisdn", "service_package.title")
    ->having('no_of_service', '>', 1)
    ->get();
```

I expect to see fields that appear more than once.

Comment: Try `havingRaw` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: It's odd that in the error query you have a `select count(*)`. I would expect this to happen when using `paginate` but not `get` as you are. is this your entire code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're using `paginate()` in your code and not `get()` as you posted. And when Laravel generates the necessary data for pagination, it overrides the `SELECT` part of your statement with:

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate
```

This is used to get the **total** entries count. That is very obvious from the SQL part of your error message:

> SQL: **select count(*) as aggregate** from cloudsubscriptions inner join service_package on cloudsubscriptions.package_id = service_package.id group by cloudsubscriptions.msisdn, service_package.title having no_of_service > 1

That of course overwrites your `no_of_service` alias definition, which can no longer be found in your `HAVING` statement when the total count is done by the paginator.

---

To work around this, you could use the aggregate function directly in your `HAVING` statement without the alias:

```php
$subscribers = Cloudsubscriptions::join("service_package", 
    "cloudsubscriptions.package_id", "=", "service_package.id")
    ->select(
        "cloudsubscriptions.msisdn", 
        "cloudsubscriptions.service_name", 
        "service_package.title",
        DB::raw("COUNT(cloudsubscriptions.msisdn) as 'no_of_service'"))
    ->groupBy("cloudsubscriptions.msisdn", "service_package.title")
    // Use the COUNT aggregate function here as well
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(cloudsubscriptions.msisdn) > 1')
    ->get();
```

It is a little annoying to have to duplicate that logic, but at least you can make use of the [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) which is a much bigger gain.

**IMPORTANT NOTE!** Make sure to use bindings with `havingRaw` and other [raw methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods) if the value comes from user input.

---

## UPDATE

Since you're using Eloquent as the starting point for your query, your can make use of [this great package](https://github.com/justbetter/laravel-pagination-with-havings) made by [Roy Duineveld](https://github.com/royduin), which fixes the issue present in the paginator and allows you to use the alias in your `HAVING` statement. You can use it by simply including a trait in your model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use JustBetter\PaginationWithHavings\PaginationWithHavings;

class Cloudsubscriptions extends Model
{
    use PaginationWithHavings;
}
```

And now you can use your original query code without any problems.

Comment: another solution, using a custom paginator ex.https://gist.github.com/ctf0/109d2945a9c1e7f7f7ea765a7c638db7 this works with any pagination related usage